# Menu implementation in swift

Tags: ios

I am trying to implementing the Menu functionality in IOS using swift for that i am trying to implement **SWRevealViewController**,   In swift in the Demo they are using segue in my project i am using stroyBoard with Identifier how to do that please help

revealViewController object  i am not able accesing in my Appdelegate.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
mainVC =  storyBoard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as? ViewController

var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC!)
navController.setViewControllers([mainVC!], animated:true)

///// **** PROBLEM Here........

[self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
////////
return true

}
```

Comment: Where is `revealViewController` set? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Actuallu SWRevealViewController.h & SWRevealViewController.m  objective-C Files i am just drage and drop to in my project(In Swift) and crated the Header Bridge file

Comment: You need to set `revealViewController` to a value before you can use it.

Comment: Yes i am trying to set in the Appdeleagte.swift  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: i am not able to create the SWRevealViewController object in my swift code